# Некорректно работает responsive в slick-slider

Tags: вёрстка, slider, slick.js, responsive

Всем привет) Хочу сделать чтоб слайдер появлялся при breakpoint 768  и ниже, но responsive работает через раз и когда слайдер все же появляеться, так он виден на всех разришениях. В чем может быть причина?

```js
$('.galeria-box').slick({
    infinite: true,
   slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
 responsive: [
     {
        breakpoint: 1920,
        settings: "unslick"
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: "slick"
      }  
    ]      
});
```

```css
.galeria-box {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.galeria-box___item,
.galeria-box___item img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 350px;
 max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="galeria-box">
    <div class="galeria-box___item">
      <img src="img/galeria-img1.png" alt="">
    </div> 
    <div class="galeria-box___item">
      <img src="img/galeria-img2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="galeria-box___item"> 
      <img src="img/galeria-img3.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="galeria-box___item">
      <img src="img/galeria-img4.png" alt="">
    </div> 
    <div class="galeria-box___item">
      <img src="img/galeria-img5.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="galeria-box___item"> 
      <img src="img/galeria-img6.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="galeria-box___item">
      <img src="img/galeria-img7.png" alt="">
    </div> 
    <div class="galeria-box___item">
      <img src="img/galeria-img8.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="galeria-box___item"> 
      <img src="img/galeria-img9.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я вопрос конечно не пытался осмыслить но возможно проблема `и когда слайдер все же появляеться, так он виден на всех разришениях` связана с тем, что JS код исполняется при загрузке страницы, а адаптивность тестируется с помощью изменения размера окна?

Answer (score 3):

Например:

```js
$('.galeria-box').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2,
      dots: true,
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.galeria-box {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.galeria-box___item,
.galeria-box___item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

.galeria-box___item img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .slick-slider .slick-list,
  .slick-slider .slick-track {
    transform: none !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .slick-slide {
    float: none;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 350px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" integrity="sha256-UK1EiopXIL+KVhfbFa8xrmAWPeBjMVdvYMYkTAEv/HI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" integrity="sha256-NXRS8qVcmZ3dOv3LziwznUHPegFhPZ1F/4inU7uC8h0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="galeria-box">
  <div class="galeria-box___item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981396-5fcf84bdf14d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="galeria-box___item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579325077603-267aa7d534d8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="galeria-box___item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579239314103-ab8c5ce59259?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="galeria-box___item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981408-db0ecd8a1ee4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="galeria-box___item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579309394590-34246e83198c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="galeria-box___item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579271723082-e06362391a46?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Смысл в том, что, для десктопных разрешений, стилями "разрушаем" поведение слайдера.

Answer (score -1):

Указал на 1 px больше и всё заработало. Например для экрана 1024 указываю 1025